# aws cli: how can use aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces to list only network interfaces bound to EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-vpc

I want to list all the network interfaces that are assigned to EC2 instances **only**, filtering out ENI assigned to things like : SageMaker Studio Domains, EFS mount targets, Route53 Resolver, Transit Gateway Attachments, VPC Endpoints vpce,  NAT Gateways, SageMaker Notebook Instances

```
aws --output json ec2  describe-network-interfaces
```

returns ENIs for EC2 instances, but there are also other ENIs there (for EFS, etc). How can I filter them out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entries for ENIs assigned to EC2 instances will have the `Attachment.InstanceId` set, for other types of ENIs this attribute will be missing.

The AWS CLI allows for [server side filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-server-side) and [client side filtering](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-filter.html#cli-usage-filter-client-side). Unfortunately, although there is a filter `attachment.instance-id`  there is no way to express "any where this is not null`, it only allows for exact matches as far as I know.

But you can use client-side filtering (`--query xxxx`) to remove all the returned NetworkInterfaces where the `Attachment.InstanceId` is `null`:

```
aws  ec2  describe-network-interfaces --query "NetworkInterfaces[?not_null(Attachment.InstanceId)]"
```

This returns only those ENIs associated with an EC2 instance.